# A polynomial class

Tags: c++

Here is the problem I am trying to solve:

> Using dynamic arrays, implement a polynomial class with polynomial addition,
>   subtraction, and multiplication. Discussion: A variable in a polynomial does nothing but act as a placeholder for
>   the coefficients. Hence, the only interesting thing about polynomials is the array
>   of coefficients and the corresponding exponent. Think about the polynomial
>   x*x*x + x + 1
>   Where is the term in x*x ? One simple way to implement the polynomial class is to
>   use an array of doubles to store the coefficients. The index of the array is the
>   exponent of the corresponding term. If a term is missing, then it simply has a zero
>   coefficient.
>   There are techniques for representing polynomials of high degree with many missing
>   terms. These use so-called sparse matrix techniques. Unless you already know
>   these techniques, or learn very quickly, do not use these techniques.
>   Provide a default constructor, a copy constructor, and a parameterized constructor
>   that enables an arbitrary polynomial to be constructed.
>   Supply an overloaded operator = and a destructor.
>   Provide these operations:
>   polynomial + polynomial, constant + polynomial, polynomial + constant,
>   polynomial - polynomial, constant - polynomial, polynomial - constant.
>   polynomial * polynomial, constant * polynomial, polynomial * constant,
>   Supply functions to assign and extract coefficients, indexed by exponent.
>   Supply a function to evaluate the polynomial at a value of type double .
>   You should decide whether to implement these functions as members, friends, or standalone functions.

This is not for a class, I am just trying to teach myself C++ because I need it as I will start my graduate studies in financial mathematics at FSU this fall. Here is my code thus far:

```
class Polynomial
{
private:
    double *coefficients; //this will be the array where we store the coefficients       
    int degree; //this is the degree of the polynomial (i.e. one less then the length of the array of coefficients)

public:
    Polynomial(); //the default constructor to initialize a polynomial equal to 0
    Polynomial(double coeffs[] , int nterms); //the constructor to initialize a polynomial with the given coefficient array and degree
    Polynomial(Polynomial&); //the copy constructor
    Polynomial(double); //the constructor to initialize a polynomial equal to the given constant
    ~Polynomial() { delete coefficients; } //the deconstructor to clear up the allocated memory

    //the operations to define for the Polynomial class
    Polynomial operator+(Polynomial p) const;
    Polynomial operator-(Polynomial p) const;
    Polynomial operator*(Polynomial p) const;
};

//This is  the default constructor 
Polynomial::Polynomial() {
    degree = 0;
    coefficients = new double[degree + 1];
    coefficients[0] = 0;
}

//Initialize a polynomial with the given coefficient array and degree
Polynomial::Polynomial(double coeffs[], int nterms){
    degree = nterms;
    coefficients = new double[degree]; //array to hold coefficient values
    for(int i = 0; i < degree; i++)
        coefficients[i] = coeffs[i];
}

Polynomial::Polynomial(Polynomial&){

}

//The constructor to initialize a polynomial equal to the given constant
Polynomial::Polynomial(double){

}

Polynomial::operator *(Polynomial p) const{

}

Polynomial::operator +(Polynomial p) const{

}

Polynomial::operator -(Polynomial p) const{

}
```

I am just wondering if I am on the right track, if there is a better way of doing this please let me know. Any comments or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it work so far? Maybe you want [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) ?

Comment: I think std::vector a better choice then double*.                                           a similar theme http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/63823/polynomial-class

Comment: You should have a look at std::set with custom comparators. It will ease your job a lot.

Comment: I am kinda lost where I go from here, and I having trouble coding the rest of the parts. Does anyone have the solution to this or something I can refer to?

Comment: I advise you to use an std::vector for the coefficients (in spite of the instructions), and state argument names in the declarations. Otherwise you're on the right track, but the hard part is still ahead of you...

Comment: Implemented addition now.

Comment: I feel like the easiest of achieving is this is using vectors and applying Gaussian elimination?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming issue: your program not working as expected, or not compiling, etc..; there is a distinct code review site for code reviews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a full answer but a starting point for you. I used std::set because it keeps its elements ordered, so I implemented a functor and used for my set. Now, elements in set will be sorted based on my comparison functor. In the current implementation, terms will be ordered in descending order in terms of exponents.

```
#include<set>

struct Term
{
    int coefficient;
    int exponent;
    Term(int coef, int exp) : coefficient{ coef }, exponent{ exp } {}
};
struct TermComparator
{
    bool operator()(const Term& lhs, const Term& rhs) {
        return lhs.exponent < rhs.exponent;
    }
};


class Polynomial
{
private:
    std::set<Term, TermComparator> terms;
public:
    Polynomial();
    ~Polynomial();
    Polynomial operator+(Polynomial p); 
};
```

My implementation allows you to store higher order polynomials efficiently.
I have implemented addition for you. It is not in best shape in terms OOP, but you can refactor it.

```
Polynomial Polynomial::operator+(Polynomial p) 
{
    auto my_it = terms.begin();
    auto p_it = p.terms.begin();
    Polynomial result;

    while (my_it != terms.end() && p_it != p.terms.end())
    {
        if (my_it->exponent > p_it->exponent)
        {
            result.terms.insert(*my_it);
            ++my_it;
        }
        else if (my_it->exponent == p_it->exponent)
        {
            result.terms.insert(Term(my_it->coefficient + p_it->coefficient, my_it->exponent));
            ++my_it;
            ++p_it;
        }
        else
        {
            result.terms.insert(*p_it);
            ++p_it;
        }
    }

    //only one of the for loops will be effective
    for (; my_it != terms.end(); ++my_it) result.terms.insert(*my_it);
    for (; p_it != p.terms.end(); ++p_it) result.terms.insert(*p_it);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: This looks really good, I am just having trouble understanding your code. If I stare longer perhaps I will see it.

Comment: Which parts did you not understand? I can try to explain if you wish.

Comment: I don't get the second part, I am still novice in C++. So, stuff like if(my_it->exponent,..etc) I don't understand at all

Comment: Yes but what is it doing?

Comment: For example, my_it points to one of the elements in terms set. By using -> , I can access members of the pointed Term instance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78885/discussion-between-seckin-savasci-and-morgan-weiss).

Answer (score 0):

**State of your code**

You code is correct so far if by `nterms` you mean maximum degree of your polynomial

> One simple way to implement the polynomial class is to use an array of doubles to store the coefficients.

This is what you did

> The index of the array is the exponent of the corresponding term

This is why I told you you array size is equal to the degree number + 1
This way you access the coefficient (the value of your array) using its degree (which will be the key)

> If a term is missing, then it simply has a zero coefficient.

Notice that in the example given, x² doesn't exist, but `coefficients[2]` exists in your code and is equal to 0

> Provide these operations: polynomial + polynomial, constant + polynomial, polynomial + constant, polynomial - polynomial, constant - polynomial, polynomial - constant. polynomial * polynomial, constant * polynomial, polynomial * constant, Supply functions to assign and extract coefficients, indexed by exponent. Supply a function to evaluate the polynomial at a value of type double

As you mentioned it, you are missing some of those operator overload.

**To go further**

Here's a non-exhaustive list of what could be done to get some more experience with C++ when you will be done with this exercise:
 - You could implement an expression parser (using )
 - Handle more complex polynomial (i.e. x² + y² + 2xy + 1)
 - Use map to store your coefficients (Map may not be considered as dynamic arrays by this exercise but could be fun for you to play with) or another data structure to get ride of your zeros in your coefficients ! (c.f. sparse matrix/arrays techniques)

Have fun in your future studies !

Comment: Thank your for the advice, but I am not sure how I should define the rest of the functions and operations that are missing, if you have an idea please share